# Setting type of an outer variable using auto lambda parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, auto

I am using a C++ web framework that heavily uses callback lambda functions. As you may guess, parameters to lambdas are usually specified as `auto` due to the must to declare very long declarations.

Now I use `decltype()` operator to find the right type deduced by `auto` so that I can declare a vector of the same type. When the vector declaration happens inside the lambda, everything is fine.

Where my problem starts is this vector needs to be declared in an outer scope using lambdas `auto` parameters' type information. Below is a simple example:

```
std::vector<T> vec; // I want the type information to be inferred just like vec2 from lambda below
auto func = [](auto parameter){
    std::vector<decltype(parameter)> vec2; // No problem here.
};
```

Is this possible?

### UPDATE:

The framework I am using is `uWebSockets`. Here is the example code :

```
using DataType = std::string;

// I had to go get type information from the source code.
static std::vector<uWS::WebSocket<false, true, DataType> *> users; 

uWS::App app {};

app.ws<DataType>("/*", {
    
    .open = [](auto * ws){
        // This is also doable
        // But not accessible in other lambdas.
        static std::vector<decltype(ws)> users2;
        // users2.push_back(ws);
        users.push_back(ws);
        ws->subscribe("sensors/+/house");
    },

    .close = [](auto *ws, int code, std::string_view message){
        users.erase(std::remove(users.begin(), users.end(), ws), users.end());

        // Not possible because not accessible.
        //users2.erase(std::remove(users2.begin(), users2.end(), ws), users2.end());
        std::cout << "Client disconnected!" << std::endl;
    },

    .message = [](auto *ws, std::string_view message, uWS::OpCode opCode){
        try{
            std::string message2 = std::string(message) + std::string(" ACK");
            for(const auto & ws2 : users)
                if(ws != ws2)
                    ws2->send(message2, opCode);

        }catch(std::exception& e){
            std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
    },
});
```

Now, nowhere in the `main.cpp`, there is a need to pass a parameter to lambda functions. That's where the main problem comes from.

Comment: Not sure what you want for `vec`... `func(42)` and `func("hello")` would produce 2 different `vec2`...

Comment: Can we get a little more example of what you are looking for?  Starting in C++17 with CTAD, you can use `std::vector vec{ initializers };` and the element type of the vector will be deduced for you.

Comment: Doc should identify type of `ws` or type of `.open` (how do you know you can call `subscribe(const char*)`?).

Comment: There isn't really a doc for this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to manually look at the type that you are initialising.

A generic lambda creates an object with a template `operator()`. There's not much stopping there from being *multiple* instantiations of that template.

If that's the case then there isn't **a** type that is the type of `auto parameter`.

You are relatively lucky here, in that the object you are initialising with all these functor members puts the arguments right in it's definition:

```
MoveOnlyFunction<void(WebSocket<SSL, true, UserData> *)> open = nullptr;
```

If you don't want to look at the definitions again, you could write a trait

```
template<typename Signature>
struct MoveOnlyFunctionTraits;

template <typename R, typename... Arguments>
struct MoveOnlyFunctionTraits<MoveOnlyFunctionTraits<R(Arguments...)> {
    using result_type = R;

    static constexpr auto arity = sizeof...(Arguments);

    template <std::size_t I>
    using argument = std::tuple_element_t<std::tuple<Arguments...>, I>;
}

template<typename Signature, std::size_t I>
using argument_t = typename MoveOnlyFunctionTraits<Signature>::template argument<I>;
```

That allows you to pull out the type

```
using websocket_type = argument_t<decltype(uWS::App::WebSocketBehaviour<DataType>::open), 0>;
std::vector<websocket_type> users;
```

Or you could submit a pull request to the library, that exposes type aliases you are interested in

```
template <bool SSL>
struct TemplatedApp {
    // existing members ...
public:
    template <typename DataType>
    using websocket_type = WebSocket<SSL, true, DataType>;
};
```

Then

```
std::vector<uWS::App::template websocket_type<DataType> *> users;
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that `auto` has no type until it is used, `auto` make it  a template call operator:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    auto func = [](auto param){
        std::cout << param << std::endl;
    };
   func(4);     // integer call
   func("lol"); //const char* call 

    return 0;
}
```

The consequence is that `param` could have any arbitrary type, before we are looking at a specific usage.

If you know the argument which will be provided, then `decltype` can be applied:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arg1 = 4;
    using Type1 = decltype(arg1); // type for the argument
    auto func = [](auto param){
        std::cout << param << std::endl;
    };
   func(arg1);  // Type1 call
   func("lol"); //const char* call 

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe you could use templates.

```
#include <vector>

template<typename type_t>
void some_function(const type_t value) 
{
    std::vector<type_t> vec;
    auto func = [](const type_t& parameter) 
    {
        std::vector<type_t> vec2;
    };

    //....
}

auto get_something()
{
    // some made up complex data type returned as auto
    using some_complex_data_type_from_somewhere_t = std::vector<std::vector<int>>;
    some_complex_data_type_from_somewhere_t value{};
    return value;
}

int main()
{
    auto value = get_something();
    some_function(value);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can "front-load" the type inference into a type alias.

```
void some_function() {
  using value_type = decltype(infer_from_somewhere);
  // alt: using value_type = typename some::annoyingly<complex>::type;

  std::vector<value_type> vec;
  auto func = [](value_type parameter){
    std::vector<value_type> vec2;
  };

  //...
}
```

Comment: Since this is a framework, the parameter is not available at any point in the main function or in the global scope. That's where the main problem comes from. What I had to do was to get into the source code, and extract the type information from there, which I didn't want to.

Comment: using isn't limited to global scope. You can do it locally inside a function too

Comment: @nmd_07 Your question says that the reason auto is used is because the types are complex and long, not that they are completely undeterminable, you should probably clarify that,

Comment: @Frank, you can declare the lambda's parameter type by looking at the source code for that specific function, but all the docs of the framework uses auto instead since declaration for that type is really long.